# C# LINQ GroupBy with NULL values

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have an object with some dates:

```
class MyObj
{
   public DateTime? Date {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see `Date` is nullable. Is it possible to use `LINQ`'s `GroupBy` method to group a `List<MyObj>` by dates including `null`s?

To get something like: `{elements_with_date_1, elements_with_date_2, ..., elements_with_no_date}`?

Comment: Yeah, it just works.

Comment: Some `SQL` languages can do it. Group by groups everything, event nulls into one bag

Comment: Do you want the list of MyObj having null date value? question is not clear

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. He has a List of objects, where some of them are null, and wants to use `.GroupBy()` on that list.

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht - The OP is specifically asking about the `Date` property, which is nullable. He makes this clear by asking about "dates including `null`s" and `"elements_with_no_date"`. That last point isn't `"elements_that_are_null"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GroupBy`-method is an extension-method, which means it is a static method which accepts your date as a parameter. It is written as `listWithNulls.GroupBy()` but actually is treated as `GroupBy(listWithNulls)`. Because of that behavior, `null`-values can be handled and you don't get a `NullReferenceException`.

Have a look at the extension-methods definition. It helps to understand how you can work with them:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector);
```

You can see the first argument written as `this IEnumerable<TSource> source`, which enables the short-handle `source.GroupBy()`.

Comment: Everything that you say here is correct, but I don't see how this answers the question?

Comment: "Is it possible to use LINQ's GroupBy method to group a List<MyObj> by dates including nulls?" -> Yes, because it is an extension-method. Sorry, if that's not clear for you, but it seems the help the OP. I didn't provide an example as you did but an explanation, which is probably appreciated more.

Comment: Yes, but he's asking about the `null` values in the `Date` property, not the source enumerable. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I see that you mean. In that case, the question does not make much sense and we all shouldn't have answered so it gets deleted. Sorry for that. Yes, my answer targets on list-items being null.

Comment: Your answer targets if the source enumerable is `null`. The answer doesn't apply to list-items that are `null`. The `keySelector` predicate would fail if the elements were `null`.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Try it out.

Comment: I just did and immediately got "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82168/discussion-between-patrik-eckebrecht-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 9):

It's not overly difficult to test it. Here's my code:

```
var items = new []
{
    new MyObj() { Date = null },
    new MyObj() { Date = null },
    new MyObj() { Date = DateTime.Now },
};

var grouped = items.GroupBy(x => x.Date);
```

I get this result:

[image: result]